# iOS: setting alphas of multiple buttons at once

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, animation, nsdictionary

Okay, so I don't really know if NSDictionary is the correct approach to this, but I am using a fade animation to take different groups of buttons on and off a screen. I want to "compartmentalize" them, so to speak, into different groups so I can do this in one or two lines without having to rewrite all the buttons names every time (there are a good amount). Any ideas on how to do this?

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 1.5
        animations: ^(void)
        {
            //As an example i just called them button1, button2, etc.
            self.button1.alpha = 1;
            self.button2.alpha = 1;
            self.button3.alpha = 1;
            self.button4.alpha = 1;
            self.button5.alpha = 1;
        }
 ];
```

I included the above as an example of what I am asking. Is there a way to put all the buttons in an NSDictionary and write one line (where the buttons are currently located) that changes all of their alphas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The preferred mechanism nowadays for buttons you've added in Interface Builder would be an `IBOutletCollection`:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *buttons;
```

[image: demonstrate hooking up outlet collection]

Clearly, in Interface Builder you would connect the individual buttons to the outlet collection. For a discussion of `IBOutletCollection`, see NSHipster's  [IBAction / IBOutlet / IBOutlet​Collection](http://nshipster.com/ibaction-iboutlet-iboutletcollection/) article.

If you're not using Interface Builder, but rather have created these buttons programmatically, you could just have an `NSArray`:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *buttons;
```

Which you'd then populate yourself:

```
self.buttons = @[self.button1, self.button2, self.button3, self.button4, self.button5, self.button6];
```

Regardless of how you build this array (either outlet collection or manually populated), you can then iterate through that array as you update a property of the buttons:

```
for (UIButton *button in self.buttons) {
    button.alpha = 1;
}
```

Or, even simpler, you can update all of them with `setValue:forKey:`:

```
[self.buttons setValue:@1 forKey:@"alpha"];
```

Comment: I notice that avismara also posted a similar answer, though I'm unclear why he deleted it. I think an outlet collection is far better than the `tag` approach.

Comment: Great answer but, What if you are not using storyboards?

Comment: @BenjaminJimenez - Then just have your own `NSArray` that you set to `@[self.button1, self.button2, etc.]` (or a mutable array that you add the buttons to as you create them). See revised answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried first with the for statement and it did not work, but the second line you had worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You can use button tags to accomplish this. Set the same tag for multiple buttons (your groups) and do:

```
button.tag = 1;
```

then:

```
for (UIButton *btn in button) {
    if(btn.tag == 1)
    {
        // do something
        break; // don't need to run the rest of the loop
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand how the tag works. so I set all of the buttons to a certain tag, then in the animation put the for loop?