# Is it possible to loop through same-class properties in order to add them to NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, loops, properties

I have 2 sets of `UIButton` properties (`IBOutlet` from Main Storyboard that are in a custom View Controller subclass header file).

There are 5 buttons per set.  In multiple methods throughout my View Controller, I need to access thes

In `viewDidLoad`, I have 2 `NSMutableArray` arrays for the 2 sets.  I `addobject:(*UIButton)` five times for each set.  In the end, it's the same line of code written 10 times for each different button.

In multiple methods throughout my View Controller, I need to access these arrays.  I have arrays in order to generate an index of which button was pressed (an index that is set in each button tap `IBAction` method).  Instead of writing out 5 methods for the buttons, I write one.

In `viewDidLoad`, is there a nifty way to condense 10 lines of repetition to a nice for-loop that can enumerate through each button and add that data to the respective `NSMutableArray`?

Or do I just write it all out?

Furthermore, based on what I've described, is this approach a bad solution to accessing and mutating multiple buttons of the same class and purpose?

In Main Storyboard, I decided to give each button a tag value (0-4).  The first set: button 1 (0), button 2 (1) ...etc.
The second: same thing.

This may only work with button interaction methods (such that a `sender` could be used to access the tag.)  In `viewDidLoad`, no such interaction occurs just yet.

This is what it looks like now:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.dirBtns = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];
    [self.dirBtns addObject:self.salineDirBtn];
    [self.dirBtns addObject:self.sampleDirBtn];
    [self.dirBtns addObject:self.airDirBtn];
    [self.dirBtns addObject:self.wasteDirBtn];
    [self.dirBtns addObject:self.lowlossDirBtn];

    self.runBtns = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];
    [self.runBtns addObject:self.salineRunBtn];
    [self.runBtns addObject:self.sampleRunBtn];
    [self.runBtns addObject:self.airRunBtn];
    [self.runBtns addObject:self.wasteRunBtn];
    [self.runBtns addObject:self.lowlossRunBtn];

    // other stuff
}
```

Comment: Oh that's fantastic, thank you very much, Rob

Comment: Another great suggestion, and one I'm probably going to use (order does matter.)  Can I change properties like the label of a `UIButton` that has it's data stored in an `NSArray`?

Comment: Yep. You just can’t add/remove items from the `NSArray`. The array is immutable, the the objects within it aren’t. (And while you don’t need it here, if you really need the array to be mutable, you could do a `mutableCopy` of the array literal.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

1. You can use array literals:

   ```
   self.dirBtns = @[self.salineDirBtn, self.sampleDirBtn, self.airDirBtn, self.wasteDirBtn, self.lowlossDirBtn];
   self.runBtns = @[self.salineRunBtn, self.sampleRunBtn, self.airRunBtn, self.wasteRunBtn, self.lowlossRunBtn];
   ```

   If you do that, you can make `dirBtns` and `runBtns` to be `NSArray` rather than `NSMutableArray`.
2. You can use outlet collections (as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31729992/1271826)), e.g.:

   ```
   @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *dirBtns;
   @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *runBtns;
   ```

   [image: hook up iboutletcollection]

   You can then hook up your buttons to these outlet collections from IB, without any code at all.

Bottom line, if order within the array mattered, I’d suggest option 1, otherwise I’d suggest option 2.

Comment: Awesome, thank you again, Rob.  I'll be using them both at some point in this application.